# What does the condition in the following code do " if (y-3) printf("1"); else printf("2"); "

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I understand a condition is supposed to be for example y==3, but y-3 is totally confusing to me. I can't understand this code. If y-3 is true it prints 1. How can y-3 be true or false?

Comment: It can be either zero or nonzero. Zero is interpreted as false, nonzero is interpreted as true, as probably any decent C book or tutorial could have informed you.

Comment: I am sorry, I searched the whole net for something similar but I guess I couldn't formulate my question right due to lack of experience. Still, I don't have time to flip trough hundreds of pages, hoping that in hours I would find my answer.
When I am actually very good at something I always feel good to help out new people no matter how inexperienced their questions are, 10 seconds from my life save an hour of flipping trough pages for another person. And when you have a site like this my question will help out other users with the same one. I will try to do better research next time.

Comment: Ripedox: I'm gonna save you a whole lot of future frustration here... Pick up a copy of [The C Programming Language](http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-2nd-Edition/dp/0131103628) and read it cover-to-cover. It's short (you can probably at least skim it in an afternoon) and most decent libraries will already have a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `y - 3` results in a value which can be tested for truthness.  In C 0 is false and any non-zero value is true.  Saying `if (y - 3)` is essentially saying `if (y - 3 != 0)` or even more succinctly `if (y != 3)`

Comment: So y-3 would take the value of y, subtract 3 from it and if it's different than 0 its true. Great, thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

In C, everything what's 0 is false and everything what's non-zero is true.

Answer (score 1):

When tested directly into a boolean context, integers can be evaluated like this.

`0` is equivalent to `false` and all the other values are considered `true`.

In your code `y - 3` will be equivalent to `false` only if `y - 3 == 0`, that is if `y` is `3`.

A better style would be to write:

```
if (y - 3 != 0)
```

Or even:

```
if (y != 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (E)`

where `E` is an expression is equivalent to

`if (E != 0)`

Answer (score 0):

In an `if` statement (or any statement with a condition), the condition is considered *true* if it's unequal to zero, *false* otherwise.

So this:

```
if (y - 3)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
if ((y -3 ) != 0)
```

which can (*and should!*) be re-written as:

```
if (y != 3)
```

The `==` operator, for example, yields an `int` value of either `1` or `0`.

C does have a built-in Boolean type (called `_Bool`, introduced by the 1999 standard), but it didn't always exist, and it's not used in conditions. Of course you can use a `_Bool` value as a condition, but it's still tested (at least conceptually) for inequality to zero.

Answer (score 0):

First, the expression 'y-3' will be evaluated. If the result is 0 (a.k.a, the value of y is 3), then the expression will evaluate to false, and the value "2" will be printed. If y is equal to any value other then 3, the condition will evaluate to true, and the value "1" will be printed

Answer (score 0):

This would mean exactly the same

```
if ((y - 3) != 0)
    printf("1");
else 
    printf("2");
```

So that's going to be true if it's not zero.